# Insert using jamierumbelow codeigniter-base-model MY_Model, where the array keys (persons, students ) are models

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do i insert this using jamierumbelow codeigniter-base-model MY_Model, where the array keys (persons, students ) are models.

```
    $data = array (
        'persons' => array(
            'firstname' => 'john',
            'lastname' => 'doe',
            'othernames' => 'Kabiri',
            'email' => 'jondoe@yahoo.com',          
            'students' => array(
                'intake' => 'BCA-2009',     
                'admission_number' => 'BCA-001-029',        
                'date_of_admission' => strtotime('now'),        
                'former_school' => 'Former School',     
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: what do you mean, they are models? in your example they simply look like keys to arrays - can you post more of your code, please?

Comment: yes they are keys to arrays but was wondering if when i pass the data array to a persons object ..... it should automatically know that on reaching student key, that data is for students table and also associate the student inserted with the person...........

Comment: sorry, you need an ORM for that sort of thing. I don't believe the MY_Model can do anything like that for you, even with relationships set up